# Create CGColor from { alpha, red, green, blue } values in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I would like to create a `CGColor` from ARGB (alpha-RGB) values. Is it possible to do it? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do the following if you have the values to pass in.

```
UIColor.FromRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha).CGColor;
```

We use a little helper class for converting hash values to UIColors as well, just incase you need it. Simply pass in a hash values ("#ffffff"). Then call .CGColor on the UIColor that it returns, or alternatively adjust the class accordingly.

```
class Colors
    {
        public static UIColor FromHexString(string hexValue, float alpha = 1.0f)
        {
            try
            {
                string colorString = hexValue.Replace("#", "");

                float red, green, blue;

                switch (colorString.Length)
                {
                    case 3: // #RGB
                        {
                            red = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{0}", colorString.Substring(0, 1)), 16) / 255f;
                            green = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{0}", colorString.Substring(1, 1)), 16) / 255f;
                            blue = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{0}", colorString.Substring(2, 1)), 16) / 255f;
                            return UIColor.FromRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha);
                        }
                    case 6: // #RRGGBB
                        {
                            red = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(0, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            green = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(2, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            blue = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(4, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            return UIColor.FromRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha);
                        }
                    case 8: // #RRGGBBAA
                        {
                            red = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(0, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            green = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(2, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            blue = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(4, 2), 16) / 255f;
                            alpha = Convert.ToInt32(colorString.Substring(6, 2), 16) / 255f;

                            return UIColor.FromRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha);
                        }

                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Invalid color value {0} is invalid. It should be a hex value of the form #RBG, #RRGGBB", hexValue));

                }
            }
            catch (Exception genEx)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```